# How to avoid show the image has same name just did remove?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, browser-cache

I try to use ajax upload images to raphael, after upload 1.jpg then remove then upload another image as same name 1.jpg.
It is show the image just did remove before, I found some similar question and answer.
So I do add value after different image url output like `<image href="..?different_value">`.
It is ok to show different image now but image width and height not be update, still the old image width and height, any suggestion within jquery or php solve this?

```
var cachenum = 0;
$('.upload_btn').click(function(){
    var uf = $('.upload form');
    var fd = new FormData(uf[0]);
    fd.append('upload','1');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){
            var session = ..., file = ... type = ...;
            function register(el) {
                // toggle handle and remove button
            };
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                var img_width = this.width, img_height = this.height;
                var img_scale = img_width / 200;
                var new_height = img_height / img_scale;
                cachenum = cachenum+1;
                var r_img = paper.image('img/product/tmp/'+session+'/'+file+type+'?'+cachenum, 0, 0, 200, new_height);
                register(r_img);
                return cachenum;
            };
            img.src = 'img/product/tmp/'+session+'/'+file+type+'?'+cachenum;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to upload multiple images to the sever? or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @user123_456 Yes, I tried to let users upload multiple images and can remove each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace variable cachenum use new Date().getTime(), it work.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use this [EXAMPLE](http://www.technodoze.com/2012/11/uploading-multiple-images-with-one.html) to upload multiple images...

Idea is to have only one input filed which can be used to upload multiple images.

There is no need for your `ajax()` calls...people are just digging so deep in this ajax calls but sometimes we can just use a simple form which will make our life much easier!

Simply use a form as you have in this example and this will make you started!

One **NOTE** this option is not working in all browsers!!! Have your thoughts on that too!

I have tested it in the Chrome and Safari and works like a charm!

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks for reply! but I can't leave ie user... and also I need to dynamic show in page, load image within Raphael.. but your example seems just upload image, can't show in page without refresh.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Please be more specific because I don't understand you correctly

Comment: I'm trying to create a page let users upload images, and dynamic show each upload in page without refresh, user can keep upload more or delete the one of those, click to remove without refresh. also user can edit(rotate, resize) within raphael freetransform

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are specifying only the src of the image

you can also add height to the image

```
img.src = 'img/product/tmp/'+session+'/'+file+type+'?'+cachenum;
img.height = new_height;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this not work, because img.height have to define at img load.. would you help me some code for example